# Jenkins pipeline input step can be advanced from blue ocean UI, but not from console output

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-blueocean

During a jenkins pipeline, when there is an input step that waits for user input, the pipeline cannot be advanced or aborted from the console output. However, these actions work fine from the blue ocean gui. 
Sample pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Input Stage.'){
            steps{
                input message: "Is?", ok: 'Continue.'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This has a console out put of:

```
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Input Stage.)
[Pipeline] input
Is?
Continue. or Abort
```

Where continue and abort are both hyperlinks to:
`https://jenkinsserver:33333/job/test_pipeline/77/console#`

Clicking either link does nothing, doesn't give an error or change pages. This is unintuitive for the user because they don't know if something is wrong or not. As I said above, both actions work fine from the blue ocean UI.

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you have not updated the JENKINS URL through Configure System.

1. Click on Manage Jenkins.
2. Clink on Configure System.
3. Update the Jenkins URL at Jenkins Location.